# How can I match a phone number of type (0)20 111 2222 using python spacy matcher

Tags: python, spacy, matcher

I am trying the following pattern:

```
pattern = [ {'ORTH': '('}, {'SHAPE': 'd'},
            {'ORTH': ')'},
            {'SHAPE': 'dd'},
            {'ORTH': '-', 'OP': '?'},
            {'SHAPE': 'ddd'},
            {'ORTH': '-', 'OP': '?'},
            {'SHAPE': 'dddd'}]
matcher.add('PHONE_NUMBER_E', None, pattern)
```

This works if i add a space to the phone number after the brackets (e.g. (0) 20 111 2222) but not otherwise. I have only started using python so I am sure I am missing something simple. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with matching with spacy vs matching strings with regex is that with spacy you [almost] never know in advance what tokenizer will do to your string:

with space:

```
doc = nlp("This is my telephone number (0) 20 111 2222")
[tok.text for tok in doc]
['This', 'is', 'my', 'telephone', 'number', '(', '0', ')', '20', '111', '2222']
```

without space:

```
doc = nlp("This is my telephone number (0)20 111 2222")
[tok.text for tok in doc]
['This', 'is', 'my', 'telephone', 'number', '(', '0)20', '111', '2222']
```

with this in mind you can write 2 patterns that will pick up both formats:

```
doc = nlp("My telephone number is either (0)20 111 2222 or (0) 20 111 2222")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)
pattern1 = [ {'ORTH': '('}, {'SHAPE': 'd'},
            {'ORTH': ')'},
            {'SHAPE': 'dd'},
            {'ORTH': '-', 'OP': '?'},
            {'SHAPE': 'ddd'},
            {'ORTH': '-', 'OP': '?'},
            {'SHAPE': 'dddd'}]

pattern2 = [ {'ORTH': '('},
            {'TEXT':{'REGEX':'[\d]\)[\d]*'}},
            {'ORTH': '-', 'OP': '?'},
            {'SHAPE': 'ddd'},
            {'ORTH': '-', 'OP': '?'},
            {'SHAPE': 'dddd'}]
matcher.add('PHONE_NUMBER_E', None, pattern1, pattern2)
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end] 
    print(span)
(0)20 111 2222
(0) 20 111 2222
```

Comment: can we make that phone number as entity too as phone number? If the text also contain a real entity like PER (person) and then with this span as label Phone and PER as person entity ?